# PyCharm 5.0.4 - Show line numbers

Tags: pycharm

I am trying to find a way to make PyCharm 5.0.4 always show line numbers. This question has been asked and answered three times for previous versions of PyCharm; in 2012, 2013, and 2014, with the most recent being for PyCharm version 4.0. The answer has always been the same 'Settings>Appearance>Always show line numbers" However, that option has changed to a different menu in 5.0.4 and I cannot find it. The menu for my Appearance Settings is attached. I have also searched Python's help menu and website. Does anyone know how to make PyCharm display line numbers for 5.0.4?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Found it! It was one level deeper. Settings>Editor>Appearance

Comment: If this is your answer, please select your own answer as the correct answer (click on the green check mark below the up/down and votes)

Answer (score 0):

On OS X El Capitan in v2016.2 of PyCharm this is found via: Preferences>Editor>General>Appearance

Answer (score 0):

The position has been moved in 5.0. See this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of menu]